# Achar um valor dentro do array e marcar o checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

Estou com dificuldades em conseguir alinhar um processo entre o php e o javascript. Tenho um script que ao clicar no botão ele marca todos os checkbox na tela, mas queria marcar apenas os que tem o valor "SIM", pois tenho uma tabela com vários sim e não, mas ao invés de marcar todos os checkbox da tela, queria marcar só os que estão com sim ao lado.

```
<?php $consultaentrega = $u->returninfotrocagelo();
foreach ($consultaentrega as $row) {
    $entreguedb = $row['Entregue'];
?>
    <script>
        var entregue = ['<?= $row['Entregue'] ?>'];
        // console.log(entregue)

        function achar() {
            entregue.find('SIM')
        }
        console.log(achar)

        function imprimir(item) {
            console.log(item);
        }



        $("#checkTodos").change(function(achar) {
            $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
        });

        $("#checkTodos").click(function(achar) {
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        var checkTodos = $("#checkTodos");
        checkTodos.click(function(achar) {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php }; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

se eu entendi bem, você tem algumas perguntas e pra cada pergunta você tem 2 `checkbox`, um sim e um não.

Se for isso, creio que você esteja usando a ferramenta errada pra esse tipo de comportamento, pois o `checkbox` permite selecionar uma ou mais opções pra mesma resposta, nesse caso você deveria usar o `radio buttom`.

o comportamento do `checkbox` funciona da seguinte forma:

quando você marca ele, ele envia o valor do input como `ON`
quando você não marca ele, o `input` não é enviado para o `PHP`

Já o `radio buttom`, sempre vai enviar um valor no `input`, seja ele qual for que você definir pra cada `radio`.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Eu nao me expressei corretamente. Tenho uma tabela com colunas e linhas, das quais tenho uma coluna onde só existem checkbox com um foreach para cara linha que vem do meu banco de dados, e tenho outra coluna onde esta dizendo se foi ou nao entregue, que seria o SIM e NÃO. Então queria uma maneira de selecionar os checkbox somente das linhas que possuem "SIM" na coluna de entregue. Como mostrei aqui no print, quando uso a função de marcar todos os checkbox, preciso que marque somente as que contenham 
"SIM" ali na coluna de entregue. https://prnt.sc/20sax5k

Comment: então é mais simples ainda, no seu foreach do PHP, na montagem do input, é só vc add a propriedade checked, ele já vai construir o input checkado.
O que exatamente vc está trazendo aqui: $row['Entregue']